# RewriteRule for long url with parameters / How do I beautify them?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I've read really everything about RewriteRules in the last weeks.
You are my last resort :D

I just cam't get anything to work (yes, Rewrite Engine is on and simple stuff works).

My site URL looks like this:

```
http://www.videospielkalender.de/?platform=wii&setfilter=1&dates=2
```

I want a result like this

```
http://www.videospielkalender.de/wii/price/nextweek/
```

That's it.
I hope some genius here can give me a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks all
Oliver

Comment: Why would that be too long? The only de-facto length limit is somewhere around 2000 bytes.

Comment: I didnt mean too long actually. I want them to be prettier.

Comment: `code`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?test\.html$ test.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /?platform=$1&setfilter=$2&dates=$3
</IfModule>

Answer (score 3):

The last recipe on http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString is the place to start. In the specific case you've mentioned above, you'd want to do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^\]+)/([^\]+)/([^\]+)/? /?platform=$1&setfilter=$2&dates=$3
```

There are two rather obvious problems with this solution however. They are:

1. how do we map "price" to "1" and "nextweek" to "2"? Perhaps this is something your handler/script/whatever needs to be made smart enough to do
2. Other URIs on your site (images, css, js, whatever) may also be caught by this ruleset, and that might break stuff.

Both of these conditions may be solved by:

1. Making the script smart enough to handle the arguments 
   and
2. Don't use mod_rewrite at all. Instead, use:

FallbackResource /index.php

(or whatever your root handler/script is called) and having that script/handler directly manipulate PATH_INFO intelligently.

Remember, the most important thing about mod_rewrite is knowing when to avoid it.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/?([^]+)/([^]+)/([^]+)/? /\?platform=$1&setfilter=$2&dates=$3

This breaks my site :D (Error 500)

Comment: Maybe yo're right and I should modify the script so it gets smarter. :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use this generic rule to rewrite the latter URL path to the former one:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /?platform=$1&setfilter=$2&dates=$3
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I enter this. I think my script has to become smarter.

Comment: @Oliver Ruehl: If you want to use this rule in the .htaccess file, remove the leading `/` from the pattern.

Comment: Nothing happens :(

RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ ?platform=$1&setfilter=$2&dates=$3

Comment: @Oliver Ruehl: You need to remove the leading `/` from the *pattern* and not from the *substitution*: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /?platform=$1&setfilter=$2&dates=$3`

Comment: Still no success. Here is the full code:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /?platform=$1&setfilter=$2&dates=$3`

Comment: @Oliver Ruehl: But you do use the obligatory `RewriteEngine on`, right?

Comment: Yes it works... on simple stuff.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /?platform=$1&setfilter=$2&dates=$3

</IfModule>